# without useState() how to disable a button in only one click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in useState we have an handler function, without this function how to disable a button after one attempt of click. I have use a Boolean variable but its not working fine

```
import React from "react";
export default function App() {
  let disable = false;
  const fun = () => {
    alert("hi");
    disable(false);  
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={disable}
        onClick={(e) => {
         if (disable) {
             disable = true;
            fun(e);
         }
        }}
      >
        Click Once
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: *without useState* - why? Why try to solve a problem with a hand tied behind your back? (the hand you need to solve the problem too)

Comment: Your boolean variable doesn't work because variables do not persist across renders. This is exactly the problem state solves.

Comment: because sometime in useState its taking time to load rather than normal variable

Comment: Why? This is explicitly what state is for; without either a state or property change React has no way of knowing anything should happen. Technically you could dive into the DOM but that's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: *because sometime in useState its taking time to load rather than normal variable* - you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Just use state.

Comment: ` taking time to load`  Your looking in the wrong place here, a useState will be pretty much instant..

Comment: so is there any solution without using useState() to solve that problem

Comment: There is no problem with `useState`, so there is no problem to solve.  You maybe need to knock up a snippet showing some issues you are having, we could then maybe recomend a solution.

Comment: I don't think not using `useState` is a good idea. Say for instance, you move the `let disable` outside of the function (before it), the value will get updated when you click the button. But the button won't render again, because from React's perspective no state change happened. A state change is what would have triggered a re-render in the first place. Now maybe you could force a re-render upon every click of the button. But that would mean you're making things too complicated for no reason.

Comment: @Shreshth and usually forcing a re-render is done with a dummy state.. so back to the same problem except now, like you said, it's more complicated

Comment: If you wish to avoid using `useState` in this scenario, what's the point of even using React, I'd say.

Comment: @SougataMukherjee Yes, you could access the DOM directly. But don't do that; there is *zero* reason to. What *specific* problem do you think you're having? State and prop changes are *core* to how React works. It is the primary mechanism used by every React app. Toggling a boolean is the simplest thing a React app could do; what about *your* boolean makes state (or a prop) the wrong choice?

Comment: What you're trying to do is better achieved with vanilla JS, no React needed.